# É seguro minificar o HTML?

Tags: html, navegador-de-internet, desempenho

Assim como o JS e CSS, o HTML também pode ser "minificado":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

viraria:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title><link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]--></head><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></body></html>
```

HTML exemplo retirado daqui: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Minificado aqui: http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

---

Isso reduz um pouco o tamanho e deve diminuir o tempo de download.

Minha dúvida é: É seguro? Ou existe o risco do navegador interpretar algo errado? (principalmente *browsers* antigos como IE<9)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Os espaços em branco podem possuir significado de forma dependente do CSS, como por exemplo ao usar `white-space: pre`.

Por isso, um minificador de HTML, que não leve em conta os estilos CSS aplicados ao mesmo, será inseguro por definição.

Obviamente, pode-se assumir algumas regras, que provavelmente nunca são burladas. A tag `head` por exemplo, nunca será visível... logo pode ter os espaços removidos.

Comentários, poderiam ser removidos, se não fossem esses comentários condicionais. Mas geralmente, esses comentários possuem um padrão, e é possível saber quando remover ou não.

Answer (score 10):

A resposta que eu vou  dar não responde exatamente sua pergunta mas acredito que inclui ***conhecimento válido para ela***.

HTML é um XML em si e por esse fator ele pode ser *maior* que um arquivo [**JSON**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) por exemplo. As inovações que estão surgindo estão todas focadas em JSON e não XML, por esse fator estão surgindo tecnologias em JS para renderizar uma página HTML usando JSON. Sendo assim é trafegado JSON e estes frameworks fazem o "parse" e o navegador renderiza o HTML5 normal.
Posso citar 2, ["AngularJS da Google"](https://angularjs.org/) e o [ExtJS da Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/).

O ganho que se tem em tamanho e final de páginas e velocidade é brutal usando estes frameworks. Se você é um desenvolvedor Web, te aconselho fortemente a estudar estas tecnologias.

Bons estudos.

Comment: +1 Boa resposta. Também tem o [ReactJS](http://facebook.github.io/react/) do facebook... o qual me impressionou muito!

Comment: Rocha e @Miguel. Eu tava antes dando uma olhada no [tutorial interativo](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) do [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/). A proposta dele é a mesmo do AngularJS ou o Angular é ainda diferente?

Comment: Pra quem tiver interesse em frameworks MVC: http://todomvc.com/

Comment: @Andrey a proposta é diferente knockoutJS tem como principal funcionalidade prover uma ideia de MVVM, ou seja, conceito de ViewModel numa página. Já o angularJS é um framework completo, aonde você pode estruturar toda sua aplicação nele usando conceito de MVC. Ele tbm provê MVVM e data-bind que é aonde o knockout trabalha, por isso as vezes eles se confundem. Dê uma lida [nesse post](http://hhide.me/KAI), ele explica algumas diferenças claras entre os 2. Em resumo o AngularJS é bem mais completo que o Knockout.