# É seguro e viável minificar os arquivos PHP?

Tags: php, minificação

Fiquei com esta dúvida depois de ler uma resposta [desta pergunta sobre HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25040/%C3%89-seguro-minificar-o-html). Tenho minificado só com PHP, só com HTML, com PHP e HTML... e não notei nenhum problema...

Será que pode se tornar um problema no servidor, ou de alguma outra forma? A renderização do HTML minificado sempre vai funcionar normal, mesmo com navegadores antigos?

Minha impressão foi de que fica muito mais rápido, mas não tenho certeza se sempre vale a pena. Vale mesmo a pena minificar os arquivos PHP?  Existe uma quantidade de linhas que passe a fazer mais sentido?

UPDATE: Vou dar dois exemplos de situações:

O primeiro é só com PHP, digamos um script "longo" (pra mim hehe, umas 1 mil linhas) que faz cálculos com datas e valores, onde tenha apenas declarações de variáveis, funções, etc, e não use HTML nunca. É viável minificar este arquivo? O ganho vale a pena?

O segundo arquivo é onde este PHP acima é embutido no HTML, template, e fica algo assim:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- DIV DO RESULTADO DA SOMA DE N + S -->
<div> 
    <label><?php // resultado da soma de n + s 
echo "Resultado<b>" . $variavelDoScript . "</b>" ?></label> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui são pequenos arquivos de uma 300 linhas desta forma, sempre embutindo o PHP através de `<?php ?>` que montam uma página através de `includes` que podem tornar o arquivo com umas 3 ou 4 mil linhas (incluindo 10 deles por exemplo)...
Neste caso vale a pena minificar todos estes arquivos? Ou só retirar os comentários já é o bastante?

Comment: retirar comentários do html ou do php?

Comment: De ambos @GuilhermeNascimento.

Comment: Editei a resposta ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se a minificação for bem feita, geralmente por um software ou script de confiança (conceituado) então não haverá problemas com o interpretador do HTML mesmo em navegadores mais antigos, a única coisa que você *talvez* deva evitar é fazer o html todo *inline*, assim:

```
<html><heade></head><body></body></html>
```

Pois mesmo que você dificilmente venha a fazer leitura da fonte em produção ainda sim pode haver alguma necessidade no futuro de analise principalmente em páginas cujo o conteúdo é dinâmico, mas se tem uma boa organização do ambiente de desenvolvimento, pode sim comprimir *inline*

Já a parte PHP (códigos entre `<?php` e `?>`) é totalmente desnecessário minificar, pois isto **não acelera quase nada** a entrega da página e nem o processamento do interpretador, pelo contrário você pode ter várias dores de cabeça, por exemplo existem muitas pessoas que escrevem `if` sem `{...}` quando ela só tem uma linha depois (o problema talvez ocorra só em algumas versões do PHP), mesmo que o script PHP tenha um milhão de linhas só de PHP minificar não vai acelerar o processamento dele, talvez até atrapalhe o interpretador do PHP.

Todavia existe uma função nativa do PHP que chamada [`php_strip_whitespace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php) que remove espaços em branco e quebras de linhas, como citado pelo @WallaceMaxters, ela pode ser usada assim:

```
<?php
echo php_strip_whitespace('outro-arquivo.php');
```

Mas lembre-se você não deve usar em execução, não vai trazer beneficio algum, o interessante é usar em sistemas de *template* que criam caches de páginas por exemplo.

Se você tem html+php, assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    ...300 linhas de HTML
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
        //1000 linhas de PHP
        ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
        //1000 linhas de PHP
        ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
        //1000 linhas de PHP
        ?>
    </div>
    <div>
    ...1000 linhas de HTML
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Só compensa comprimir o HTML, o PHP não compensa como já citei, o que você pode tentar fazer pra facilitar é usar frameworks que suportam Views, como Laravel e Cakephp, então você vai separar o HTML dentro das Views e a maior parte da lógica vai ficar no Controller e no Model, ou você também pode usar `include` pras partes HTML comprimidas assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php include 'arquivo-com-300-linhas-de-html-comprimidas-em-uma.php'; ?>
</div>
<div>
<?php
//1000 linhas de PHP
?>
</div>
<div>
<?php
//1000 linhas de PHP
?>
</div>
<div>
<?php
//1000 linhas de PHP
?>
</div>
<div>
<?php include 'arquivo-com-1000-linhas-de-html-comprimidas-em-uma.php'; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Quanto a comentários PHP, não compensa remover eles pois não fará muita diferença na performance, já os do HTML se forem muitos ou muito extensos é melhor remover.

Ferramentas pra comprimir o HTML:

- https://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/
- http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Também pode ter interesse em minificar arquivos como CSS e JS:

- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/
- http://www.phpied.com/cssmin-js/
- https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler
- http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

### Acelerando o PHP

Um detalhe que vale ressaltar é que o PHP é uma linguagem interpretada, quero dizer a cada requisição os arquivos PHP serão reprocessados antes de serem executados, a linguagem em si não possui-a nativamente [**JIT**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_in_time) (Just in time), apesar de possuir [`Opcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) a partir do PHP5.5 (é necessário habilitar), em versões mais antigas é necessário instalar manualmente ou via [*PEAR*](https://pear.php.net) ou até mesmo compilar manualmente (o mais provável em servidores Linux).

Extensões como [`Opcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) e [`Xcache`](https://xcache.lighttpd.net) melhoram em muito a performance de sites em PHP, pois não será necessário ficar interpretando os scripts para cada requisição, mais detalhes em:

- [PHP trabalha com cache?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166747/3635)

### PHP 8  JIT (Just-In-Time)

A partir do PHP8 (apesar de possuir uma parte experimental no PHP7.4) temos o dois motores de compilação [***JIT**, **Tracing JIT** e **Function JIT***](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.jit).

Notem que OPCache em si já existia, mas o recurso dos motores que citei (`opcache.jit`) é que é novo.

Comment: Se puder adicionar a referência, no php temos uma função chamada `php_strip_whitespace`, que retorna um código php compactado. Você precisa passar o nome do script como argumento :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters interessante para usar em templates com cache né :) hehehehe. Vou adicionar.

Comment: Então, eu adicionei um update com duas situações diferentes, se puder dar uma olhada... +1

Comment: É verdade, eu vou implementar isso hoje no `Legendary\View` :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu não tenho certeza, mas acho que `php_strip_whitespace` remove comentários também ;)

Comment: Então, no caso não inclui tantas linhas de php, no início do arquivo tem o include do script, da parte só PHP, que já entendi que não vale a pena minificar né... mas nestes outros arquivos é mais 300 linhas de HTML cada um com algumas variáveis PHP embutidas no meio, no máximo alguma chamada de função... então é muito mais HTML e só algum PHP. Mas quando monta, pode ficar um arquivo bem grande, então neste caso não dá problema ter as chamadas das variáveis do PHP ali no meio?

Comment: @gustavox quando você só usar algo como `<div><?php echo 'oi'; ?></div>` e não tiver uma lógica complexa então você pode minificar tudo, incluido o php ;)

Comment: Foi introduzido o JIT no PHP 8 para cima, seria interessante acrescentar isso na publicação :)

Comment: @CypherPotato resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 6):

O que você deveria minificar é o conteúdo enviado para o navegador do usuário, HTML, Javascript e CSS. Minificar seu código PHP não traz vantagens, apenas complica seu processo de desenvolvimento.

Caso seu HTML esteja no meio do PHP, digamos com blocos `?> HTML|JS|CSS <?php` ou fracionado em `echo string` até faria algum sentido, contudo o ideal é você ter o "grosso" desse conteúdo em arquivos separados que você possa minificar e enviar, no caso de JS e CSS é simples, mantenha eles em arquivos .js e .css o máximo que puder tentando atender a [separação de conceitos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_conceitos). Já para HTML é um pouco mais complicado pois você quer gerar ele dinâmicamente (afinal é para isso que você está usando PHP) contudo existem alternativas bem aceitas como o uso de linguagens de templates tipo [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html), [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) e [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), as quais ficam em arquivos separados que podem ser minificados a parte do seu código código php.

Também tenha em mente que minificar pode ser desnecessário no seu contexto, embora salvar uns KBs de banda do usuário sempre seja algo bom talvez você esteja fazendo um projeto interno para um ambiente, não algo acessível para o mundo na www, neste caso para que se preocupar com um acréscimo de alguns milissegundos no carregamento da página sendo que isso vai complicar sua vida.

Comment: Então, eu adicionei um update com duas situações diferentes, se puder dar uma olhada... +1

Comment: @gustavox Não vou colocar na minha resposta porque acredito que ela já responde a sua pergunta, mesmo com a edição que você fez. Mas respondendo de forma direta o seu update: o seu script longo que é puro PHP não deve ser minificado pois não traz vantagem nenhuma, PHP não é enviado para o cliente e minificar PHP não acelera seu processameto. Já o seu segundo arquivo parece uma versão simplificada dos sistemas de template que comentei, então sim, este é o arquivo que você deve minificar pois é onde o conteúdo que vai chegar no browser do usuário se encontra.

Answer (score 3):

**Não terá problemas algum,** o espaçamento, tabulações são mais visuais do que realmente necessárias.

**Porém minificação só é recomendável se você tem algo que faça isso para você**, digo, que você ainda tenha seu código fonte indentado corretamente. Pois senão será um sufoco a manutenção.

Realmente pode ficar mais rápido o carregamento pois você remove bons bytes de espaço em branco, em navegações mobile (que normalmente são mais lentas) a diferença pode ser bem notável.

Desconheço alguma ferramenta que faça minify no PHP Somente para css, js, etc.

Porém se a forma de minify for direto no código esqueça! O Ganho de desepenho é tão mínimo (e também para SEO) que não vale a pena minify o PHP.

> OBS: Na verdade é impossível você minificar o PHP, o que você faz é
>   minify o html gerado pelo HTML, já que o PHP é interpretado pelo
>   Servidor e enviado o html para o cliente.

Comment: Então, eu adicionei um update com duas situações diferentes, se puder dar uma olhada... +1