# PHP trabalha com cache?

Tags: php, select, cache

Estou notando que minha aplicação está ocorrendo algum erro, ou então meu navegador está sempre guardando cache, mesmo eu realizando a limpeza.
Tenho um arquivo `.php` e nele contêm a função `loadEvent`, que é responsável por realizar consultas `select`.
Acontece que eu altero a instrução `select` para trazer um resultado diferente, salvo o arquivo `.php`, atualizo o navegador, mas o resultado continua vindo do `select` anterior.
Depois de um minuto, sem eu fazer nada no código, o navegador passa a interpretar o `select` alterado.
Então eu pergunto: Existe alguma possibilidade do `.php` trabalhar com cache nessa situação?

Comment: oisw ser cache do seu navegador, do php , do apache. Este teste que vc faz é online?

Comment: localhost, na minha máquina. Eu removi todo o cache do navegador.

Comment: mais provável que a plataforma q você ta programando ta guardando cache mesmo ou seu navegador. geralmente quem guarda cache no apache sao os servidores grandes como locaweb e uol para otimizar o  acesso

Comment: eu te afirmo, não é cache no navegador.

Comment: entao esta na sua aplicação teria q ver nela c ela guarda cookie ou se ha alguma pasta guardando os arquivos php cacheados

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O PHP não usa cache por padrão, ele pode ser feito usando a função `header();`, mas como você disse que removeu o cache do navegador e mesmo assim continuou a exibir os mesmos resultados então o problema deve ser alguma extensão de [*Bytecode*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) (leia também sobre [*just-in-time (JIT)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation))

O PHP é uma linguagem interpretada, ou seja a cada requisição e cada pessoa que acessa o script terá que ser interpretado, as extensões [*Bytecode*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) "salvam" as várias das "interpretações" do script na "memoria", uma versão "compilada" do código, fazendo com que o script não precise ser completamente processado, ou seja só vai processar algumas coisas, isso trás muitas vezes vantagens no tempo execução de um script e menor consumo dos recursos do servidor o que é uma grande vantagem para o **ambiente de produção**.

Recursos para PHP:

- **Compilação Just-In-Time**

  A partir do PHP8 temos o dois motores de compilação: [**Tracing JIT** e **Function JIT**](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/)
- **OPcache**

  No PHP 5.5 é padrão e pode ser habilitado via `php.ini`. Já nas versões 5.2, 5.3 e 5.4 do PHP só pode ser instalado via [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache), ou manualmente baixando as extensões compiladas ou compilando por conta própria)
- **APC** (não confundir com [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu))

  Pode ser instalada desde o PHP 5.1 usando [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/apc)
- **[XCache](https://github.com/lighttpd/xcache)** (provavelmente descontinuada)

  Mantida pelo mesmo grupo que mantém o [*lighttpd*](https://www.lighttpd.net/), pode ser instalado no PHP 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 e 5.6

Ou seja no momento que você altera o código como:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo=?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_GET['foo']);
```

Para algo como:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT foo,nome,sobrenome FROM bar WHERE foo=?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_GET['foo']);
```

Dependendo da extensão o script ainda funcionará como primeiro, a única coisa que muda o comportamento é `$_GET['foo']`, isto porque a linguagem foi compilada para provavelmente uma *linguagem intermediária* (não precisa ser uma linguagem completa), sendo assim os valores dinâmicos continuam a mudar, mas o roteiro do script não.

A própria extensão geralmente detecta mudanças, mas geralmente leva alguns segundos ou precisará com que ou reinicie o servidor http (exemplos: Apache, nginx, lighttp, etc).

Se estiver em **ambiente de desenvolvimento** o recomendável é desligar a extensão no `php.ini` comentando as extensões com ponto e virgula.

> Se estiver em desenvolvimento e usando funcionalidades internas do APC pode experimentar trocar pelo *APCu* ou pelo [*memcache*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)

- Para desligar o OPcache você pode comentar a linhas assim (se for Unix-like):

  ```
  ;zend_extension=opcache.so
  ```

  Se for Windows:

  ```
  ;zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
  ```

  Você também pode fazer isto:

  ```
  opcache.enabled=0
  ```
- Para desligar o APC você pode comentar a linhas assim (se for Unix-like):

  ```
  ;extension=apc.so
  ```

  Se for Windows:

  ```
  ;extension=php_apc.dll
  ```

  Você também pode fazer isto:

  ```
  apc.enabled=0
  ```
- Para desligar o XCache você pode comentar a linhas assim (se for Unix-like ou PHP7+):

  ```
  ;extension=xcache.so
  ```

  Se for Windows com PHP inferior ao 7:

  ```
  ;extension=php_xcache.dll
  ```

---

> 1. **Nota:** O [HHVM](http://hhvm.com) já tem o próprio JIT
> 2. **Nota:** Os compiladores *bytecode* apesar de levar alguns segundos para limpar o "cache" das versões "compiladas", então se precisar que as modificações nos arquivos `.php` sejam aplicadas de imediato, talvez você tenha que reiniciar o servidor HTTP ou o FastCGI (depende qual módulo o seu servidor usa).