# Problema em insert não apresenta erro

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Pessoal tudo beleza? Eu já fuçei o fórum inteiro e até outros fóruns e não achei respostas sobre isso.
 Se alguém puder dar uma olhada e apontar o meu erro agradeço.

Segue o  formulário:

```
   <form action="add.php" method="post" name="form1">
   div> <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered' style="background-color:white;">


    <tr>
        <td>Data de Cadastro:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Nome Fantasia:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nomefantasia"  required autofocus class='form-control'/>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Razão Social</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="razaosocial"  required class='form-control'/><td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>CNPJ:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cnpj"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
        <td>Inscrição Estadual:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="inscricaoestadual"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>           

   <tr>
        <td>Categoria:</td>
        <td><select name="categoria" size="1">
                     <option>Selecione...</option>
                     <?PHP mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());

                        mysql_select_db('suinos') or die(mysql_error()); 
                        mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");
                        ?>
                     <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT categoria_id, categoria_titulo FROM comp_categoria");
                     while($categoria = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
                     <option class='form-control' value="<?php echo $categoria['categoria_id'] ?>"><?php echo $categoria['categoria_titulo'] ?></option>
                     <?php } ?>                      
            </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Endereço:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="endereco"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Número:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="numero"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Bairro:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bairro"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>

    <td>CEP:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep"  required class='form-control'/>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Cidade:</td>
        <td>
            <select name= "cidade"><option>Escolha a cidade</option> 

                     <?php $queryy = mysql_query("SELECT Id, Nome FROM comp_cidade ORDER BY Nome ASC");
                     while($cidade = mysql_fetch_array($queryy)) { ?>
                     <option class='form-control' value="<?php echo $cidade['Id'] ?>"><?php echo $cidade['Nome'] ?></option>
                     <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> Estado:</td>
        <td><select name="estado" size="1">
                     <option>Selecione...</option>

                     <?php $bquery = mysql_query("SELECT Id, Nome FROM comp_estado ORDER BY Nome ASC");
                     while($estado = mysql_fetch_array($bquery)) { ?>
                     <option class='form-control' value="<?php echo $estado['Id'] ?>"><?php echo $estado['Nome'] ?></option>
                     <?php } ?>

            </select></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
        <td><input type="email" name="email"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Contato:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="contato"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Telefone:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fone"  required class='form-control'/> 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> Nome do Banco:</td>
        <td><select name="banco">
                     <option>Selecione...</option>

                     <?php $bquery = mysql_query("SELECT id_banco, nomebanco FROM fat_bancos");
                     while($nbanco = mysql_fetch_array($bquery)) { ?>
                     <option class='form-control' value="<?php echo $nbanco['id_banco'] ?>"><?php echo $nbanco['nomebanco'] ?></option>
                     <?php } ?>

            </select></td>
    </tr>    
        <tr>
        <td>Número da conta</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nconta"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Número da Agencia:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nagencia"  required class='form-control'/></td>
    </tr>

         <td>
            <center>
            <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary">      
            </center>
        </td>           
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td>


    </tr>
    </table>


   </div>
   </form>
```

E aqui o PHP com o insert:

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/NovoModelo/config.php");


if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {



$nomefantasia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['nomefantasia']));
$razaosocial = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['razaosocial']));
$endereco = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['endereco']));
$numero = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['numero']));
$bairro = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['bairro']));
$idcidade =  $_POST['cidade'];
$idestado = $_POST['estado'];
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['email']));
$contato = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['contato']));
$fone = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['fone']));
$cnpj = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['cnpj']));
$cep = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['cep']));
$inscricaoestadual = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['inscricaoestadual']));
$nbanco = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['banco']));
$nconta = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['nconta']));
$nagencia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['nagencia']));
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];


 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO comp_fornecedor(FORN_ID, FORN_NOMEFANTASIA, FORN_RAZAOSOCIAL, FORN_ENDERECO, FORN_NUMERO, FORN_BAIRRO, FORN_IDCIDADE, FORN_IDESTADO, FORN_EMAIL, FORN_CONTATO, FORN_FONE, FORN_CNPJ, FORN_CEP,FORN_INSCRICAOESTADUAL, FORN_CATEGORIAID, FORN_IDBANCO,FORN_NCONTA,FORN_NAGENCIA) 
VALUES('','$nomefantasia', '$razaosocial', '$endereco','$numero', '$bairro', '$idcidade', '$idestado', '$email', '$contato', '$fone','$cnpj','$cep','$inscricaoestadual','$categoria','$nbanco','$nconta', '$nagencia')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

}
?>
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: ele está em uma  pagina externa. Na qual estou chamando no include.

Comment: "or die(mysqli_error))" eu coloquei pra apresentar erro  e mesmo assim nada.

Comment: No insert não seria `...or die (mysql_error())`? Está somente `(mysql_error)`

Comment: corrigido o or die (mysql_error()). Mesmo assim, nada ainda.

Comment: veja que a variavel  $razaosocial tem que estar envolvida em aspas simples como as demais.

Comment: Rapaz, eu criei um banco só pra testar isso e está funcionando perfeitamente. Dá para você editar a sua pergunta e colocar todo o codigo corrigido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para exibir o erro, se é que há algum erro na query você deve usar `mysqli_error` e não `mysql_error`, isto **esta errado**:

```
 or die(mysql_error));
```

Fora que o `mysqli_query` não tem o parenteses no final `)`, em:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO comp_fornecedor(FORN_ID, FORN_NOMEFANTASIA, FORN_RAZAOSOCIAL, FORN_ENDERECO, FORN_NUMERO, FORN_BAIRRO, FORN_IDCIDADE, FORN_IDESTADO, FORN_EMAIL, FORN_CONTATO, FORN_FONE, FORN_CNPJ, FORN_CEP,FORN_INSCRICAOESTADUAL, FORN_CATEGORIAID, FORN_IDBANCO,FORN_NCONTA,FORN_NAGENCIA) 
VALUES('','$nomefantasia', $razaosocial, '$endereco','$numero', '$bairro', '$idcidade', '$idestado', '$email', '$contato', '$fone','$cnpj','$cep','$inscricaoestadual','$categoria','$nbanco','$nconta', '$nagencia')" or die(mysql_error));
```

O correto deveria ser isto:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO comp_fornecedor(FORN_ID, FORN_NOMEFANTASIA, FORN_RAZAOSOCIAL, FORN_ENDERECO, FORN_NUMERO, FORN_BAIRRO, FORN_IDCIDADE, FORN_IDESTADO, FORN_EMAIL, FORN_CONTATO, FORN_FONE, FORN_CNPJ, FORN_CEP,FORN_INSCRICAOESTADUAL, FORN_CATEGORIAID, FORN_IDBANCO,FORN_NCONTA,FORN_NAGENCIA) 
VALUES('','$nomefantasia', $razaosocial, '$endereco','$numero', '$bairro', '$idcidade', '$idestado', '$email', '$contato', '$fone','$cnpj','$cep','$inscricaoestadual','$categoria','$nbanco','$nconta', '$nagencia')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Provavelmente você não esta vendo nenhum erro porque os erros devem estar desligados no php.ini:

```
display_errors=Off
```

Recomendo que se for no seu computador habilite, basta editar o php.ini:

```
display_errors=On
```

Após ajustar é necessário reiniciar o Apache ou Nginx ou LightTTPD ou IIS

Também verifique se `error_reporting` esta igual a `E_ALL`, pode ser alguma configuração no teu `NovoModelo/config.php`, veja se não ajustou o a função `error_reporting(...);`.

Eu recomendo mesmo que leia isto para entender sobre os erros em PHP:

- [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)

Note também que talvez seus ajustes nos scripts não tenham efeito porque esta usando opcode, como por exemplo *Xcache*, *Apcache* ou *Opcache*, recomendo que leia isto:

- [PHP trabalha com cache?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166747/3635)

### Não misture mysql_ com mysqli_

Notei que você esta misturando `mysql_` que são funções da API antiga com `mysqli_`, isto deve estar causando o problema todo, recomendo que mude tudo para *mysqli* que é a API mais nova, aqui eu explico motivo do porque não usar as APIs antigas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66489/3635

Veja aqui por exemplo você misturou mysqli_ e mysql_:

```
 <option>Selecione...</option>
 <?PHP mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('suinos') or die(mysql_error());  <--- Aqui
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8"); <--- Aqui
    ?>
 <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT categoria_id, categoria_titulo FROM comp_categoria");
 while($categoria = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
 <option class='form-control' value="<?php echo $categoria['categoria_id'] ?>"><?php echo $categoria['categoria_titulo'] ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
```

Outra coisa não é necessário ficar abrindo conexão com o servidor mysql várias vezes para cada `<select>` que você criou, basta uma vez e pegar o *handle*, outra coisa que faltou foi escapar algumas variáveis, faça assim:

```
$nomefantasia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nomefantasia']);
$razaosocial = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['razaosocial']);
$endereco = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['endereco']);
$numero = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['numero']);
$bairro = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['bairro']);
$idcidade =  mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['cidade']);
$idestado = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['estado']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
$contato = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['contato']);
$fone = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['fone']);
$cnpj = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['cnpj']);
$cep = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['cep']);
$inscricaoestadual = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['inscricaoestadual']);
$nbanco = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['banco']);
$nconta = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nconta']);
$nagencia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nagencia']);
$categoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['categoria']);
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59525/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-problema-em-insert-nao-apresenta-er)

Answer (score 1):

> Sua query tem erros:

- `mysqli_error` e não `mysql_error` conforme meu comentário que por sinal tb tem erros :) o correto é  `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))`
- a variavel  `$razaosocial`  tem que estar envolvida em aspas simples como as demais.

  ```
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO comp_fornecedor(FORN_ID, FORN_NOMEFANTASIA, FORN_RAZAOSOCIAL, FORN_ENDERECO, FORN_NUMERO, FORN_BAIRRO, FORN_IDCIDADE, FORN_IDESTADO, FORN_EMAIL, FORN_CONTATO, FORN_FONE, FORN_CNPJ, FORN_CEP,FORN_INSCRICAOESTADUAL, FORN_CATEGORIAID, FORN_IDBANCO,FORN_NCONTA,FORN_NAGENCIA) 
  VALUES('','$nomefantasia', '$razaosocial', '$endereco','$numero', '$bairro', '$idcidade', '$idestado', '$email', '$contato', '$fone','$cnpj','$cep','$inscricaoestadual','$categoria','$nbanco','$nconta', '$nagencia')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
  ```

Comment: Corrigi mas, continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Rapaz, eu criei um banco só pra testar isso e está funcionando perfeitamente. Dá para você editar a sua pergunta e colocar todo o codigo corrigido?

Comment: Editei,  me desculpe sou novo e estou me adaptando ao fórum.

Comment: Deve ter algo a ver com o meu banco de dados então. Estou usando o phpmyadmin. Estou dizendo isso, porque criei uma outra página com um formulário simples. Criei a tabela  para o teste. E não está salvando e nem retornando erros.