# Concatenação ou sequenciação de dados: qual tem melhor desempenho?

Tags: php, desempenho

Há uns dias estava escrevendo uns artigos sobre PHP, na qual fui questionado sobre uma possível melhora de desempenho em *large scale* na hora de desenvolver aplicações em PHP. A suposição foi a seguinte:

A impressão de dados via `echo` do PHP é extremamente utilizada na hora do desenvolvimento das aplicações. Numa situação onde você recebe milhões de requisições no servidor a toda hora, então precisa obter o máximo de desempenho do servidor, qual seria a melhor forma de exibir dados distintos na mesma função?

```
<?php

  #método 1 - Exibindo dados em sequência
  $nome = "Daniel";
  echo "Bem vindo, ", $nome; // mostra na tela: "Bem vindo, Daniel"
  #método 2 - Usando concatenação
  $nome = "Daniel";
  $frase = "Bem vindo, ".$nome;
  echo $frase;  // mostra na tela: "Bem vindo, Daniel"

?>
```

Eu chamei o método apresentado pelo questionador de sequenciação de dados por não saber exatamente como esta prática realmente se chama. Lembrando que como o `echo` não é de fato uma função, de acordo com o manual do PHP, então não seriam considerados 2 parâmetros de fato.

> `echo` não é uma função atualmente (construtor da linguagem) então não é obrigatório usar parênteses. echo (diferente de outro construtor da linguagem) não se comporta como uma função, então ele nem sempre é usado no contexto de uma função. Sendo assim, se você quer passar mais de um parâmetro para echo, os parâmetros não precisam estar entre parênteses.

Comment: Faltou outro exemplo: `$frase = "Bem vindo, {$nome}"`

Comment: De forma geral, não é relevante. Só testando para saber. E depende de versão, do interpretador usado.

Comment: Vou falar uma coisa, isto é micro-otimização, não afeta em nada as vezes, existem coisas que fazemos em nossos códigos além disto, como criar classes enormes ou incluir classes e funções sem necessidade que estas sim podem ter problemas de performance para o script final. Concactenar strings raramente vai causar algum impacto, só em um teste de "stress" bem longo que sentirá alguma variação e ainda sim será minima o que não vale a pena se dar ao trabalho. Uma coisa interessante para usar em produção é Opcache ou XCache: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166747/3635

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Para deixar claro: como dito pelo [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215063/5878) e pelo [Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215051/concatena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ou-sequencia%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dados-qual-tem-melhor-desempenho#comment442659_215051), tem muitos outros fatores que influenciam mais na performance que este detalhe. **Se possuir problemas de performance no seu projeto, não será isso que te salvará**.

Por curiosidade, utilizando o site [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org), executei alguns testes.

### Teste 1 - `echo` com múltiplos valores constantes ([link](https://3v4l.org/e38n0))

```
echo "Anderson", "Carlos", "Woss";
```

O resultado da performance pode ser visto em diferentes versões do PHP abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verificando a análise de *OP Codes* fornecida, temos:

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Jump found. (Code = 62) Position 1 = -2
filename:       /in/e38n0
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  4
compiled vars:  none
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ECHO                                                     'Anderson'
         1        ECHO                                                     'Carlos'
         2        ECHO                                                     'Woss'
         3      > RETURN                                                   1
```

Ou seja, quando executado desta maneira, o que acontece de fato é a chamada da instrução `echo` três vezes, cada uma com um parâmetro.

### Teste #2 - `echo` com concatenação de valores constantes ([link](https://3v4l.org/hQmo3))

```
echo "Anderson"."Carlos"."Woss";
```

O resultado da performance pode ser visto em diferentes versões do PHP abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verificando a análise de *OP Codes* fornecida, temos:

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Jump found. (Code = 62) Position 1 = -2
filename:       /in/hQmo3
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  2
compiled vars:  none
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ECHO                                                     'AndersonCarlosWoss'
         1      > RETURN                                                   1
```

O que parece acontecer nesse caso é o interpretador do PHP já efetuar a concatenação dos valores antes do código ser executado, então a instrução `echo` é chamada apenas uma vez, já com a *string* final. Isso porquê os valores passados são constantes e o interpretador consegue fazer tal otimização (se é que pode ser chamada assim).

### Teste #3 - `echo` com múltiplos valores com variável ([link](https://3v4l.org/N4IMI/))

```
$nome = "Anderson";

echo "Bem vindo, ", $nome;
```

O resultado da performance pode ser visto em diferentes versões do PHP abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verificando a análise de *OP Codes* fornecida, temos:

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Jump found. (Code = 62) Position 1 = -2
filename:       /in/N4IMI
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  4
compiled vars:  !0 = $nome
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, 'Anderson'
   5     1        ECHO                                                     'Bem+vindo%2C+'
         2        ECHO                                                     !0
         3      > RETURN                                                   1
```

Novamente vemos que o que acontece de fato é a chamada duplicada de `echo`, uma com o valor constante, outra com a variável definida.

### Teste #4 - `echo` com concatenação com variável ([link](https://3v4l.org/FfLnC))

```
$nome = "Anderson";

echo "Bem vindo, ". $nome;
```

O resultado da performance pode ser visto em diferentes versões do PHP abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verificando a análise de *OP Codes* fornecida, temos:

```
Finding entry points
Branch analysis from position: 0
Jump found. (Code = 62) Position 1 = -2
filename:       /in/FfLnC
function name:  (null)
number of ops:  4
compiled vars:  !0 = $nome
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, 'Anderson'
   5     1        CONCAT                                           ~2      'Bem+vindo%2C+', !0
         2        ECHO                                                     ~2
         3      > RETURN                                                   1
```

Agora possuindo uma variável envolvida, podemos perceber que o processo de "otimização" ocorrido anteriormente não é mais possível, sendo assim ocorrendo, de fato, a chamada do operador de concatenação.

Não sei quanto esses dados podem ser conclusivos, mas é possível verificar que o processo de concatenação se mostrou mais rápido que as múltiplas chamadas de `echo` quando passados vários valores separados por vírgula.

Answer (score 8):

Sempre que se fala em performance de linguagem, faz sentido discutir isso quando se programa em Assembly, C, C++, até mesmo C#, Java, quem sabe Rust, D, ou Delphi.

Em PHP a solução é muito simples se precisa de performance da linguagem. Troque de linguagem. Este não é o ponto forte da linguagem. Ela é uma linguagem de *script*. Se está preocupado em atender milhões de requisições (que em geral não acontece) e acha que a linguagem tem papel fundamental nisso, mais que algoritmos bem feitos ou que já fez tudo o que podia nos algoritmos, então não será isto que resolverá algum problema, opte por uma linguagem mais escalável.

Sempre que quer saber o que tem performance melhor tem que medir. Medir certo. Saber que pode mudar de acordo com a implementação da linguagem. Não é algo que sempre será igual.

Sem conhecer a implementação exata destas formas vou chutar com base no meu conhecimento sobre computação e de como as linguagens costumam ser implementadas.

Acho que passar vários parâmetros deve ser o mais rápido porque ele só precisa ler os caracteres e enviar para a saída de forma simples. Note que a saída deve ser absurdamente mais lenta que ler os dados, então deve fazer pouca diferença.

Concatenar tem que criar uma nova *string* copiando os dois dados e depois fazer a leitura de todos os caracteres juntos para enviar para a saída. Isto é, se não tiver nenhuma otimização, o que acredito que não tenha mesmo.

Fazer interpolação de *string*, se não tiver otimizações, pode ser mais rápido que a concatenação, mas ainda dependerá de uma certa interpretação. Se o interpretador não transformar a interpolação em uma sequência, haverá um certo [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101), sem falar no próprio *overhead* gerado pela interpretação do que é texto e o que é código ali dentro.

Note que até mesmo [o uso de aspas simples ou dupla afetará a performance da interpretação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15290/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

**Isto é micro-otimização**, não afeta em nada as vezes, existem coisas que fazemos em nossos códigos além disto, como criar classes enormes ou incluir classes e funções sem necessidade que estas sim podem ter problemas de performance para o script final.

Concatenar strings raramente vai causar algum impacto, só em um *teste de "stress"* bem longo que sentirá alguma variação e ainda sim será minima o que não vale a pena se dar ao trabalho.

### O porque o echo usa virgula

O motivo do `echo` usar `,` não é por questões de performance, tanto que em uma máquina ou versão do php em um teste de stress bem pesado `echo 'a'.'b';` pode **eventualmente** ser melhor que `echo 'a', 'b';` e no próximo teste na mesma máquina pode ser que não, vai depender do **momento**, o motivo mesmo é para facilitar o uso outras coisas como fazer uma operação matemática, veja a diferença:

```
<?php
echo '0', 5 + 2, '3', PHP_EOL; //Resulta em 073

echo '0' . 5 + 2 . '3', PHP_EOL; //Resulta em 73
```

Então note que o zero acabou sendo "confundido" com parte da operação matemática no segundo `echo`

Isto é apenas um exemplo, existe bem mais situações aonde usar o virgula será bem mais pratico e poderá lhe facilitar.

### Concluindo

Sobre a sua pergunta

> Numa situação onde você recebe milhões de requisições no servidor a toda hora, então precisa obter o máximo de desempenho do servidor, qual seria a melhor forma de exibir dados distintos na mesma função?

Respondendo a pergunta algo como isto `echo 'foo' . $bar;` contra `echo 'foo', $bar;` não terá diferença alguma perseptiva, o que pode afetar e o que geralmente afeta nesta questão podem ser inúmeras outras coisas, como coisas que muitas vezes podem talvez ser desnecessárias (que deveriam só acontecer as vezes, mas vc acaba por fazer executar quase sempre):

- Frameworks gigantes para coisas simples, como usar Laravel ou cakephp para criar um site de 3 páginas simples
- Execuções de "pedidos", como acessar em um banco de dados e não fazer nada, nem mesmo um `SELECT` ou `UPDATE`
- Iniciar funções sem necessidade ou em página que não são necessárias, como iniciar um `session_start` em uma página que não precisa de sessão

Existem mais coisas podem afetar, mas é bastante relativo

### Como melhorar a performance do meus scripts

Fora você evitar as situações que comentei acima, uma outra coisa interessante para usar em **produção** (não use em ambientes de desenvolvimento) é Opcache ou XCache:

- [PHP trabalha com cache?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166747/3635)

O PHP não tem nada como o *JIT* (Just In Time) nativamente, no entanto existe a extensão *Opcache* que pode ser habilitada em servidores com PHP5.6+ (para versões anteriores você tem que instalar manualmente ou via *Pearl* e nem todos servidores permitem isto), o PHP é uma linguagem interpretada, sem 1000 pessoas requisitam uma página o PHP vai reinterpretar os scripts para aquela requisição 1000 cada e depois executa-los, mas com Opcache (ou outros alternativos como XCache) a **interpretação** do código fica em um tipo de **"cache"**, ou seja é interpretado "uma vez" (aproximadamente) e fica em "cache" por algum tempo, assim as próximas requisições irão apenas executar.

O Opcache (ou outros) ao menos em testes que eu fiz melhoram em muito, até mesmo em um teste com ApacheBench (ferramenta para simular múltiplas requisições simultâneas) melhorou em muito o tempo de resposta, executei o seguinte comando:

Sem Opcache:

```
Requests per second: 2176.80 [#/sec] (mean)
```

Com Opcache:

```
Requests per second: 2350.93 [#/sec] (mean)
```

Parece que o numero não mudou, mas faça as contas `2350 - 2176 = 174`, o Opcache conseguiu `174` requisições em um segundo a mais que sem Opcache, ou seja é como se 174 pessoas a mais tivessem conseguido acessar aquela página em apenas **1 segundo**, agora imagine em uma hora (claro que isto tudo é relativo).

O teste foi feito com um script bem simplório, se tivesse classes, includes, conexão com banco, você pode até notar uma melhora maior, segue o script de teste:

```
<?php

$nome = 'Stack OVerflow';

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    echo 'Olá ', $nome, '<br>';
}

echo memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024, 'Kb';
```