# Melhores práticas para montar a condição do IF

Tags: php

Faz um tempo que eu tenho a seguinte dúvida: teria alguma diferença de desempenho entre declarar um *IF* dessas duas maneiras?

Ou mesmo que não tenha diferença na questão de desempenho, alguma dessas formas é mais correta do que a outra?

Forma 1

```
if(date('N', strtotime($data)) == 3)
```

Forma 2

```
$d = date('N', strtotime($data));

if($d == 3)
```

Comment: Em relação a desempenho tem diferença, a segunda forma tem uma variável a mais, ou seja, um espaço a mais na memória sendo alocado.
Agora qual forma é mais a bonita, isso varia de pessoa pra pessoa. Eu prefiro a primeira

Comment: Bem colocado pelo @RobertodeCampos. Eu, particularmente, sempre prezo pelo desempenho.

Comment: Se vc for precisar do valor em `$d` posteriormente, a segunda forma é melhor; se não, a primeira seria melhor.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho então eu recomendo rever alguns conceitos. PHP não foi feito para ter desempenho, então essas diferenças, tal como perguntada, são irrelevantes para a aplicação, fazendo com que a legibilidade e semântica devem ser sempre prioridade. Se tal diferença de desempenho é relevante para aplicação, PHP não é a linguagem mais indicada.

Comment: Além que o recurso utilizado em ambos os códigos são os mesmos, visto que o PHP precisa armazenar o retorno da função em memória para utilizar na validação da expressão. A diferença é que com a variável ele valor fica acessível pelo desenvolvedor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim como discutido na pergunta [Concatenação ou sequenciação de dados: qual tem melhor desempenho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215051/5878), esse tipo de preocupação com desempenho em relação à linguagem não faz muito sentido. É sabido que o PHP não foi criado para ser uma linguagem performática, então micro-otimizações no código não irão alterar o resultado e devem ser evitados quando ao fazê-las a legibilidade e semântica são prejudicadas. Prefira sempre o código que é mais fácil de ler do que aquele que é supostamente mais rápido.

Você pergunta se há diferença de desempenho entre os dois códigos, não há, exceto se você executá-lo milhares de vezes para então começar a ver alguma diferença. O consumo de recursos das duas soluções é o mesmo. Mesmo que na segunda existe uma variável e na primeira não, o PHP irá precisar armazenar o retorno da função na memória de qualquer forma, a diferença é que com a variável o valor ficará acessível ao desenvolvedor (de maneira direta).

Mesmo que não haja diferença de desempenho, você pergunta qual é o melhor. Na minha opinião, nenhuma das duas formas, pois ambas são difíceis de ler e não são claras quanto ao objetivo. Lendo a documentação, é possível perceber que o parâmetro `N` de `date` irá retornar um número referente ao dia da semana de uma determinada data: 1 para segunda-feira, 7 para domingo. Se está verificando se é igual a 3, precisa saber se determinada data é uma quarta-feira. Nenhuma das formas deixa isso claro.

A forma que eu faria é:

```
$isWednesday = (date('N', strtotime($data)) === "3");

if ($isWednesday) {
    ...
}
```

Desta forma, eu não preciso recorrer à documentação da função `date` para saber o que o código está fazendo, pois o nome da variável me diz que estou verificando se é quarta-feira.

Comment: Entendi o que você quis dizer no comentário. Realmente, não faz muita diferença no php, pois geralmente ele é lido uma vez apenas, não faz sentido você prezar pela performance e deixar de lado a semântica.

Answer (score 3):

Como já foi dito nos comentários a segunda forma é menos performática  (a diferença, nesse caso, é irrelevante) por ter uma variável sendo criada antes, exemplificando...

No primeiro a função é executada, é feito um gasto X de recursos (memória, processamento...), depois é feita uma verificação, mais um gasto Y.

Na segunda é criada uma variável, gasto Z, e atribuída a ela a execução da função, gasto X, e depois é feita a comparação, gasto Y.

Porém se vai ser feitas muitas verificações com o mesmo valor que vem de uma função é melhor guardar o resultado em uma variável do que executar a mesma função diversas vezes, a não ser claro que em cada verificação mude o valor ao fazer a execução

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria da primeira forma.

Se usasse um nome de variável que service como documentação do que é aquilo aí eu poderia fazer da segunda forma, mesmo que ficasse um pouco mais lento (talvez nem fique). Mas só faria isto em algo que realmente não fosse óbvio. Seria algo como nosso amigo Anderson fez, mas ali acho desnecessário, mas é só o meu gosto, pode ser bom para programadores iniciantes lerem o código e entender o que está fazendo ali.

Ou eu faria uma função com a condição que retornasse true ou false e chamaria a função no if.

Tudo isso é só uma forma de demonstrar melhor o que você está fazendo. Um comentário pode ser mais eficiente em casos assim.