# IF x SWITCH - Simulando

Tags: php, switch

Acredito que todos nós sempre tempos que fazer algumas tratativas em condições com poucos valores.

Fiz um ***teste*** entre o `IF` e o `SWITCH`.

> Todo conteúdo, foi criado para ***SIMULAR*** uma estrutura mais idêntica
>   possível entre o `IF` e `SWITCH`.

Arquivo da classe: `ifXswitch.php`

```
<?php

class Teste {


    public function fc_if($v) {

        // Marcador de tempo 1
        $t1 = microtime(true);


        // Script
        if ($v == 1) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(1); }
        elseif ($v == 2) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(2); }
        elseif ($v == 3) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(3); }
        elseif ($v == 4) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(4); }
        elseif ($v == 5) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(5); }
        elseif ($v == 6) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(6); }
        elseif ($v == 7) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(7); }
        elseif ($v == 8) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(8); }
        elseif ($v == 9) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(9); }
        else { echo 'Número inválido'; }


        // Marcador de tempo 2
        $t2 = microtime(true);


        // Tempo final
        $t3 = $t2 - $t1;


        return $t3;
    }

    public function fc_switch($v) {

        // Marcador de tempo 1
        $t1 = microtime(true);


        // Script
        switch ($v) {

            case '1':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(1);
            break;

            case '2':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(2);
            break;

            case '3':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(3);
            break;

            case '4':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(4);
            break;

            case '5':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(5);
            break;

            case '6':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(6);
            break;

            case '7':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(7);
            break;

            case '8':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(8);
            break;

            case '9':
            echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(9);
            break;

            default:
            echo 'Número inválido';
            break;
        }


        // Marcador de tempo 2
        $t2 = microtime(true);


        // Tempo final
        $t3 = $t2 - $t1;


        return $t3;
    }


    public function calcula($v) {

        $vf = pow($v,5);

        sleep(1);

        return $vf;
    }


    public function resultado($t_if, $t_switch) {

        echo '<hr>';
        echo '<br> Tempo IF: ' . $t_if;
        echo '<br> Tempo SWITCH: ' . $t_switch;

        if ($t_if < $t_switch) $r = 'IF';
        elseif ($t_if == $t_switch) $r = 'Empate';
        elseif ($t_if > $t_switch) $r = 'SWITCH';
        else $r = 'Erro';

        echo '<br> Menor tempo: ' . $r;
    }

}

?>
```

Executor: `mitrotime.php`

```
<?php

include_once 'ifXswitch.php';

$exemplo = new Teste();
$t_if = $exemplo -> fc_if(9);
$t_switch = $exemplo -> fc_switch(9);
$exemplo -> resultado($t_if, $t_switch);

?>
```

Na execução do teste, varia muito, hora ganha o IF hora o SWITCH, e até incrivelmente deu empate uma vez.

Gostaria de saber, entre eles, se algum tem vantagem sobre o outro em algum aspecto (por ex., com números o SWITCH seria melhor !?), ou se trata de necessidade e organização ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre Switch, Case e If, Else?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58192/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-switch-case-e-if-else)

Comment: @Articuno Atualizada... confere aí por favor...

Comment: Esse exemplo provavelmente não é o melhor pois todo conjunto de ifs poderia ser reduzido a `echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula($v);`

Comment: É que fiz pensando em manter a "estrutura" igual entre eles, para terem as mesmas quantidades de condições... usei números, mas também poderia ser string... e ainda mesmo assim precisei colocar o `sleep(1)` porque estava dando 0.

Comment: Sempre que precisar comparar performance em PHP, leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215063/5878) e as demais.

Comment: "Em PHP a solução é muito simples se precisa de performance da linguagem. Troque de linguagem. " o Maniero já vem com os 2 pés... rs

Comment: Mesmo o próprio echo seria mais fácil com interpolação: `echo "<br>$x elevado a 9 = {$this->calcula($v)}";`

Comment: Eu estava tentando gerar tempo, porque estava dando `0` :'[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se fizer uma execução de mais de um bilhão de loops, talvez você sinta alguma diferença perceptível ao usuário, mas no geral não fazem diferença que tenha significado, 15 condições por exemplo nem notaria nada.

Tenha em mente que cada versão do PHP ter uma performance diferente, a versão 7 inclusive é bem mais eficiente que a 5, também existe a possibilidade de usar "cache" (não tem nada haver com cache do navegador), é semelhante ao JIT (talvez possa ser chamado assim), leia mais em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166747/3635

Pra resumir, não existe diferença significativa entre `switch` e `if`, o que eles diferem é em suas necessidades, por exemplo da forma que usou o `if` e `switch` você escreveu o código já de maneira ineficiente em ambos casos, ou seja boa parte das perdas de performance é a maneira que usamos e não entre os tipos.

**Os problemas reais de performance** estão na maneira que escrevemos e não em duas funcionalidades da linguagem, claro que tem exceções, mas quase todas são somente em micro-otimização, o que é algo que as pessoas deveriam parar de se preocupar e se preocuparem mais com os erros graves que os programadores cometem que realmente vão afetar a velocidade

Pode vir alguém aqui e falar que `switch` é melhor, mas isso em PHP não é necessariamente uma realidade, já que a maneira que se escrever os seus IFs pode resultar em algo mais performático (micro-otimização, o que geralmente costuma ser insignificante), e como eu disse existem variações de comportamento entre as versões do PHP, mas não adianta ir muito a fundo.

O que você precisa entender é que `IF` tem hora, lugar e maneira melhor de trabalhar e o mesmo vale para `SWITCH`, tem hora, lugar e maneira melhor de trabalhar.

O que vai tornar mais lento ambos é a maneira que você escreve eles, se souber lidar bem com as condições é capaz de que ambos tenham o mesmo resultado (como eu disse use conforme a necessidade).

**Outros fatores** que podem consumir mais o script, tipo execuções de funções repetidas em cada checagem, que é um erro bastante comum entre programadores, por exemplo:

```
function foo()
{
     return file_get_contents('./version');
}

if (foo() == 1) {
    echo 'Versão 1 do App, atualize para a versão 2 ou 3, este esta obsoleto';
} elseif (foo() == 2) {
    echo 'Versão 2 do App';
} elseif (foo() == 3) {
    echo 'Versão 3 do App';
}
```

Veja que no código acima foi executado 3 vezes no minimo (dependendo do conteúdo do arquivo `./version`), agora se fizer assim:

```
$versao = foo();

if ($versao == 1) {
    echo 'Versão 1 do App, atualize para a versão 2 ou 3, este esta obsoleto';
} elseif ($versao == 2) {
    echo 'Versão 2 do App';
} elseif ($versao == 3) {
    echo 'Versão 3 do App';
}
```

Irá com certeza executar somente uma vez o `foo()`, e como a resposta já esta salva no `$versao`, isso com certeza irá tornar o script mais performático.

---

Agora uma sugestão sobre o seu código, o problema que vejo em seus códigos é a repetição desnecessária, por exemplo isto:

```
if ($v == 1) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(1); }
elseif ($v == 2) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(2); }
elseif ($v == 3) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(3); }
elseif ($v == 4) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(4); }
elseif ($v == 5) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(5); }
elseif ($v == 6) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(6); }
elseif ($v == 7) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(7); }
elseif ($v == 8) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(8); }
elseif ($v == 9) { echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula(9); }
else { echo 'Número inválido'; }
```

Poderia ser simplesmente isso:

```
if ($v >= 1 && $v <= 9) {
    echo '<br>' . $v . ' elevado a 9 = ' . $this -> calcula($v);
} else {
    echo 'Número inválido';
}
```

Pronto, você terá reduzido o seu código a duas linhas, o que com certeza irá melhorar um pouco a performance do analisador (que faz parte do interpretador de scritps), que foi o que citei no começo da resposta, o problema esta mais em como escrevemos as IFs do que em outros fatores.

Comment: O intuito era só simular as 2 com a mesma quantidade de condições... assim elas iriam percorrer as 9 condições. Quis deixar o mais próximo um do outro !

Comment: Eu entendi, mas era outra ideia a pergunta... acho que já fugiu total do contexto... rs

Comment: Eu entendi tudo o que disse... Por exemplo "repetição desenecessária" que você postou... eu só fiz isso para equiparar exatamente o IF com SWITCH, encher processo para dar tempo.... A pergunta não foi nesse contexto... mas tranquilo... não dá para excluir agora...

Comment: Da mesma forma que você não entendeu a pergunta amigo. Eu fiz uma SIMULAÇÃO para ser IGUAL entre os 2. Parece que eu nem ser fazer um IF da forma que você respondeu. Da mesma forma que deu o -1 para mim por não entender a pergunta, dei o -1 por achar a resposta incorreta. Estamos com entendimentos divergentes nessa questão ! Está tranquilo ! ;]

Comment: Perai, acho que eu me expressei errado. A sua resposta concordo com isso: "Pra resumir, não existe diferença significativa entre switch e if, o que eles diferem é em suas necessidades", só aqui sim, entendi o que quis dizer. Mas o intuito da simulação foi somente SIMULAR, então eu precisava deixar ao máximo um igual ao outro e "gerar processamento". Eu fiquei "triste", pois você tratou a pergunta como se fosse cheia de erros ! E pelo contrário, eu sempre procuro total eficiência no código... A sua resposta ficou 90% tratando de "erros" que foram propositais entendeu ?

Comment: Quando ao downvoter, foi por esse motivo. Concorda comigo que sua resposta fugiu do contexto da pergunta ? Se você simplesmente tivesse colocado esse pedacinho que citei, já era praticamente 90% da questão. Vou tirar o downvoter porque tem parte correta e parte incorreta, entende !?

Comment: Pode ter total certeza, que eu sei o pessoal que manja demais aqui no SOpt, e claro, eu sempre vou olhar com atenção tudo que falam... sou um mero iniciante, e quanto mais aprendo, menos sei ! rs

Comment: Jamais uso o downvoter atoa, mas como foi que eu fiz a escolha foi sobre isso: a resposta sua focou em 90% em erro de utilização, e os erros foram propositais para a simulação. Entendeu ?

Comment: @RBZ a resposta não fugiu do contexto, é que voce não entendeu, a respsota indica exatamente que você  esta a se preocupar com coisas e se esquece de entender o essencial da linguagem e que com experiencia de mais de 14 anos com PHP lhe digo, os problemas reais de performance estão na maneira que escrevemos e não em duas features da linguagem, claro que tem exceções, mas quase todas são somente em micro-otimização, o que é algo que as pessoas deveriam parar de se preocupar e se preocuparem mais com os erros graves que os programadores cometem que realmente vão afetar a velocidade.

Comment: Pronto ! Perfeito ! Está aí sua resposta: "os problemas reais de performance estão na maneira que escrevemos e não em duas features da linguagem, claro que tem exceções, mas quase todas são somente em micro-otimização, o que é algo que as pessoas deveriam parar de se preocupar e se preocuparem mais com os erros graves que os programadores cometem que realmente vão afetar a velocidade" Incrementando: o IF e o SWITCH são praticamente iguais. ! o foco foi que entrou muito no contexto da estrutura (que foi proposital)... mas está tranquilo ! Agradeço a ajuda com toda sinceridade !

Comment: @RBZ na verdade foi isso que eu disse desde o começo da pergunta, só que com outras palavras, para ser sincero e me perdoe, mas muitas pessoas noto que são assim como você, não é uma critica do mal, mas sim construtiva, geralmente falta um pouco de pratica de leitura para absorver o enunciado da postagem, claro que eu também posso tentar melhorar o texto e torna-lo mais agradável, mas não é fácil de escrever e tornar o texto intuitivo de primeira. De qualquer forma vou editar e postar isso dentro do corpo/conteudo da resposta. Boa sorte e sucesso!

Comment: A crítica pode ser mais efetiva que o elogio se soubermos recebê-la ! Sempre ouço e processo ! rs Foi um tópico ímpar que a "linguagem de comunicação" atrapalhou a "linguagem de programação" rs !! Obg ! Abs !