# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function phperror_reporting()

Tags: php

Colegas

Em uma determinada página do projeto está dando o erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function phperror_reporting()

Porém o código está dessa forma:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
.....
```

Porque esse erro está acontecendo se no editor ATOM o error_reporting(0) aparece embaixo da tag PHP?

Comment: Qual codificação o ATOM mostra do script? UTF-8/windows-1252?

Comment: Olá Guilherme, está como Unicode(UTF-8)

Comment: Mas é UTF-8 com BOM ou sem BOM? Tentou apagar a quebra de linha e adiciona-la novamente?

Comment: Como não sei ver pelo ATOM, abri o Notepad++ e mostra sem BOM.

Comment: Tentou apagar a quebra de linha e adiciona-la novamente e verificar se o Opcache esta ativo na sua máquina (no php.ini)?

Comment: Quebrei a linha novamente e vou dar uma olhada no link que você me passou abaixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente o PHP não está reconhecendo a quebra de linha e está mesclando

```
<?php
error_reporting
```

em:

```
<?phperror_reporting
```

Recomendo que apague a quebra de linha e tente a adicione novamente, também verifique se não esta ativado o Opcache ou XCache em tua máquina: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166747/3635, isto quer dizer que você pode ter corrigido o problema, mas o cache impede de ver, se o cache for no servidor de produção então não aguarde um pouco que logo ele irá se renovar, o cache é muito importante para a performance do site.

Comment: Olá Guilherme. Fiz a sua primeira sugestão de recriar a quebra de linha e parece que funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda.