# Como usar Eloquent sem perder a performance (51.39%) em Lumen 5.4?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, desempenho, laravel-eloquent, lumen

Desenvolvendo uma API que deve lidar com um site alta performance. Fazendo alguns testes verifiquei que o uso do Eloquente está baixando a performance das requisições no banco de dados **MySQL** em **51.39%** (mais da metade). O SO é **ubuntu 16.04** e o framework é o **Lumen 5.4**. A query seleciona todas as cidades da tabela cities (5565 cidade).

```
//Rota
$app->get('cities', 'CitiesController@index');
```

Este é controller Cities CitiesController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Citie;

class CitiesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return DB::select("SELECT * FROM cities");
        //return Citie::all();
    }
}
```

Este é o Model Citie:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Citie extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=['id'];
}
```

Estou usando **POSTMAN** para fazer as 10 requisições para cada abordagem (Com e sem Eloquente).

```
Com Eloquente - >  return Citie::all();
Sem Eloquente - >  return DB::select("SELECT * FROM cities");
```

E estes são os resultados em milisegundos(ms):

Sem Eloquent:

```
1975
1698
1809
1817
1918
1841
1897
1689
1854
1958
média - 1845.6
```

Com Eloquent:

```
3449
3684
3654
3667
3546
3491
3462
3531
3614
3815
média - 3591.3
```

O resultado é que neste teste o uso do Eloquent está diminuindo a performance da requisição em 51.39 % comparado com o cenário sem Eloquent.

Aqui um exemplo do output:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o sql de criação da tabela cities:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cities`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `fk_province` INT NOT NULL,
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `geocodeBr` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'null',
  `lat` DECIMAL(10,8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `long` DECIMAL(11,8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_city_province_idx` (`fk_province` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_city_province`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fk_province`)
    REFERENCES `provinces` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Então a questão é como usar o Eloquent de maneira que ele atinja a média dos resultados do teste sem uso de Eloquent, no caso - 1845.6 ms, ou seja, sem perder esse desempenho de pouco mais de 50%?

Alguma configuração que está faltando?

Nota:
Esta é uma instalação fresca do Lumen 5.4. Só retirei os comentários de Facade e Eloquent em `bootstrap/app.php` como sugerido pela [documentação oficial](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/database).

Comment: Eu não fiz teste de desempenho no Lumen, mas, de anti mão o `DB::select` vai ser sempre mais rápido do que a classe `ORM Eloquent`, o `DB::select` retorna um um `array` de `stdClass` ou seja, simples `array` já o `ORM Eloquent` vai retornar uma `Collection` do tipo da classe, cada item é uma estrutura complexa, anexada a um contexto e cada item se pode manipular seus dados para alterar e até excluir! então são coisas diferentes e por padrão o Lumen desabilita o uso do Eloquent, já mesmo por causa do desempenho. Ou seja, é assim mesmo não tem o que alterar.

Comment: Eu já desconfiava da vagareza do uso do Eloquente pois ele carrega outras classes e segue outros caminhos para retornar a resposta. Só não imaginava que fosse tanto assim ( mais de 50%).  Então esse é o preço considerado aceitável para se trabalhar com Models e Eloquent?

Comment: Não é lento o `Eloquent` (alguns vão dizer esse cara é louco, kkk) é assim que ele foi feito e a maioria dos `FULL ORM` são assim, no caso especifico está gerando uma lista de valores e pela arquitetura do `Eloquent` ele não traz um dado simples, mas, sim um collection (que é uma classe) e dentro dela uma coleção de itens de uma determinada classe imagine você que cada item dessa classe pode ser alterada e salva, já no outro que é um SQL pura ele não tem essas funcionalidades é um dado seco, se pede para o banco o resultado ele te devolve, o Eloquent o transforma, ai está a diferença.

Comment: Já pensou em usar HTTP cache e possivelmente um "back-end cache"? Dá uma lida nisto que postei: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166747/3635