# Comentários pesam?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, desempenho

Comentários pesam?

Eu deixar comentários em todo meu código, vai influenciar em alguma coisa no site?

Estou dizendo mais especificamente em HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP.

Comment: **Relacionado:** [É seguro e viável minificar os arquivos PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113963/3635)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pesar até pesam, mas você provavelmente usa um [minificador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88058/101), certo? Aí eles desaparecem e não pesam mais.

Eles pesariam se estivessem presentes porque é mais conteúdo para trafegar não só aumentando ligeiramente o tempo de espera do usuário, mas também consumindo banda que alguém tem que pagar. Pode não ser muito, mas se você serve milhões de páginas (dá diferença para você, menos para quem recebe). O processamento no cliente também pesa já que tudo isto precisa ser interpretado. Mas é **ínfimo** porque só pesará na fase inicial de interpretação que já costuma ser um consumo muito baixo.

Em PHP pesa também pela interpretação, cada caractere tem que ser interpretado. Mas também depois de fazer o [*parsing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99632/101) não tem peso mais.

Em linguagens compiladas não pesam. Assim como espaços e qualquer coisa que suma na compilação. Até pesam, mas não afetará o desempenho da execução, pesam no processo de compilação, e será ínfimo também, em geral imperceptível porque mesmo em exagero deve ser uma diferença bem inferior a 0,001%.

Então use comentários onde realmente precise deles para facilitar o entendimento e minifique depois para tirar esse irrisório peso. Mas antes faça um código legível que quase não precisará de comentários. Organize seu código para todos poderem ler bem, aprenda fazer isso porque é fácil, dá resultado e mostra profissionalismo.

Existe um mito que código bom é código cheio de comentários. Na verdade é o oposto disto. Quanto mais comentários, mais o código é ruim. Claro que tem casos que o comentário é necessário porque não pode ser expressado toda a complexidade de um problema em código. Em geral comentários devem dizer o porquê e não o que está fazendo. Se tiver que escrever o que, mude o código para ficar mais legível.

Leia:

- [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre linguagem compilada para linguagem interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101)
- [Como saber a medida certa de comentários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15488/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você disse "minificador" eu as vezes até penso em usar, mas fico com medo do mesmo "estragar" meu código, remover alguma coisa, etc... Pôs ja aconteceu de eu usar com JavaScript e ele parar de funcionar. Por isso nunca uso, e talvez seja um erro meu isso, não usar.

Comment: É porque você usou um ruim. Ou o JS já tinha problemas e o minificador apenas expôs mais facilmente.

Comment: Recomenda algum? Que serve pra todos os tipos de linguagens?

Comment: No *link* que eu postei tem uma lista deles.

Comment: Eu vi, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Cada caractere contribui para o peso do arquivo, mas para influenciar negativamente no desempenho tem que escrever muuuuito, sendo assim, comente livremente. Os comentários são de muita ajuda quando formos fazer manutenção do código.
Visualmente eles não influenciam no site ou sistema, eles não aparecem.

Comment: Muito obrigado Gabriel!

Answer (score 3):

Tendo HTML como base com certeza eles irão pesar, porém pode ser uma diferença insignificante.

Você pode utilizar algum preprocessador para comprimir seu site antes de envia-lo para produção, assim o Script removerá todos os comentários.

Dependendo da maturidade da sua aplicação isso não se faz necessário pois estará se preocupando com algo que na prática não trara resultados visíveis para o usuário. Pois a diferença no final serão de poucos kb, ou nem isso.

Comment: Obrigado, Mauricio! 

"Você pode utilizar algum preprocessador para comprimir seu site antes de envia-lo para produção, assim o Script removerá todos os comentários." 

No caso eu queria manter os comentários, pra melhor edição depois, se precisar. Melhor edição, digo, ser mais fácil me localizar. Mas então o recomendável é não ter comentários?

Comment: Você terá dois códigos. Um que irá enviar para o servidor e um que irá usar para edição. Antes de enviar para o servidor você pode usar o Gulp para cópia de seus arquivos removendo comentários

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer. Muito obrigado!