# Comentários pesam o código em C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

Utilizo a linguagem C# com a Unity Engine e, como vários programadores possuem acesso ao código costumamos comentar bastante para que todo mundo possa entender o que tem ali. Vi em outras respostas recomendações para utilizar um minificador mas eram sempre relacionadas a linguagens para desenvolvimento web. Isso seria útil/se aplica para C# neste caso? Como posso estar otimizando essa parte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como `C#` [normalmente é usado de forma compilada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125588/c-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-compilada-ou-interpretada), o próprio compilador deixa os comentários de lado, ou seja, eles não interferem no tamanho ou na performance do seu programa.

Definitivamente comentários não são algo que você vai precisar se preocupar nessa linguagem, porém existem outras inúmeras formas pra otimizar sua folha de `C#`. Nesse [link](http://www.macoratti.net/10/09/c_ocod1.htm) tem algumas dicas que valem a pena conferir.

Answer (score 7):

Viu [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199201/101), certo? Apesar de lá dizer que praticamente não faz diferença, o contexto não é web e sim linguagens interpretadas.

Minificação é necessária para a transmissão do código. O ganho é muito pequeno para a compilação que ocorre no cliente. O único motivo para minificar é que o fonte trafega pela rede. Com o [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101) esse problema acaba porque o código é compilado antes.

[C# é compilada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125588/101), então até pesam para fazer um *parsing*, porque é mais texto para avaliar, mas é algo ínfimo, desprezível, não faz nem *cosquinha* no compilador. Para a execução o comentário tem peso zero por todas as formas que analise já que eles desaparecem por completo.

C# tem outras coisas que vão para a execução que pesam e as pessoas não se dão conta :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você comentou sobre outras questões pesarem que geralmente não nos damos contas, alguma dessas coisas seria no modo de escrever o código?

Comment: @dotSonic sim..

Comment: você poderia me dar um exemplo? ou mais de um. ou isso não é assunto para falar nos comentários?

Comment: Exato, são vários, é uma lista fica complicado listar, porque quase que a lista não tem fim, eu nem saberia classificar os principais. Eu dei uma palestra bastante incompleta onde tinha centenas de itens, e praticamente só falei do C#, nem entre no .NET :D Estou sempre postando coisas que podem ajudar na minhas redes sociais (no meu perfil).

Answer (score 5):

Os comentários são ignorados pelos compiladores/transpiladores aquando da análise léxica pelo quando o código é compilado os comentários são sempre passados à frente, nem sequer estando nos ficheiros binários executáveis.

A razão pela qual se usa a minificação em desenvolvimento web é que o cliente transfere o ficheiro `.css`, `.js`, etc e depois é que faz a leitura do ficheiro localmente. Todos os comentários, espaços em branco a mais e linhas em branco são igualmente ignoradas no entanto o cliente já fez download do ficheiro com elas, gastando largura de banda e espaço.

A minificação serve então para ter a certeza que os ficheiros no desenvolvimento web seguem apenas com o que realmente é necessário para a página e, em alguns casos, chegam ao ponto de trocar os nomes das variáveis para usarem menos caracteres.

Recursos úteis:

- [Minificar pra que? Uma breve explicação](https://woliveiras.com.br/posts/minificar-pra-que/)
- [Construção de compiladores/Análise léxica](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_compiladores/An%C3%A1lise_l%C3%A9xica)

Answer (score 3):

Como o C# é compilado, os comentários são ignorados pelo compilador, ou seja, não há perda de *performance*. Dê uma olhada na lógica do seu sistema, talvez a maneira com que foi escrita esteja pesando.