# Usar ou não definição de bloco em "if" simples influencia no desempenho da aplicação?

Tags: delphi, desempenho, if, sintaxe, programação-estruturada

Entre uma linha e outra surgem algumas dúvidas que não alteram em nada o fluxo de decisões, mas talvez possa influenciar no desempenho da aplicação pela quantidade de linhas extras dependendo da maneira como se programa.

Eu gosto de manter meus códigos o mais enxuto possível, porém quando se trata de manter organizado não poupo linhas de código.

Nessa ânsia de manter um código bem legível eu costumo sempre abrir e fechar um bloco de comandos como no exemplo abaixo:

```
if (a = b) then
begin
  ShowMessage('A é igual a B');
end;
```

Vejam que existe somente uma linha dentro do `if`, porém "eu gosto" sempre de abrir o `begin` e `end`, pois se amanha tiver que inserir mais linhas o bloco já está pronto e não tenho que ficar procurando fim de `if`, faço isso mesmo que seja aninhados de `if`s simples, exemplo:

```
if (a = b) then
begin
  ShowMessage('A é igual a B');
end 
else 
begin
  if (a = c) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('A é igual a C');
  end;
end;
```

Eu poderia reduzir o número de linhas desses `if`s, mas "gosto" desse modo de trabalhar.

Agora a pergunta do tema:

> **O uso de mais linhas como nos exemplos acima, será que influencia no desempenho da aplicação?**
>
> - Imagino que quanto mais linhas independente de qualquer coisa o processador e memória vão trabalhar um pouco mais, certo?
> - Ou será que o compilador é inteligente o suficiente para ignorar os `begins` quando se trata de um `if` simples?

Essa dúvida me veio pela questão da aplicação já estar com milhares e milhares de linhas de código, agora como citado, não sei e esses milhares são somente linhas consideradas válidas pelo compilador para a execução da aplicação ou se todas as linhas dentro do executável.

Outro exemplo, mas agora com "comentários"

```
// Esse bloco de comentário será ignorado pelo compilador?
// Não
// Importa
// Quantas
// Linhas
// Tenha?  
if (a = b) then
  ShowMessage('A é igual a B');
```

O número de linhas acima é maior que um `if` simples com `begin` e `end`, mas imagino que o compilador trata diferente de um bloco de comando, pois mesmo sendo comentário o processador terá que ler a linha para saber do que se trata.

Um exemplo que eu particularmente detesto, mas pode ser mais eficiente:

```
if (a = b) then
  ShowMessage('A é igual a B')
else if (a = c) then
  ShowMessage('A é igual a C');
```

Talvez essa possa ser uma discussão inútil, mas no dia a dia conforme a aplicação vai crescendo percebemos que o desempenho cai um pouco a cada novo Formulário, assim sendo qualquer mudança de hábito na programação que venha contribuir para melhorar esse desempenho pode ser válido.

**Obs: Dei como exemplo o Delphi (Pascal), mas é válido para qualquer linguagem.**

Comment: Seria melhor você contextualizar na forma de uma pergunta e postar isso como sua resposta. Porque como está, foge de como o site funciona. É um Q&A, precisa ter uma pergunta e uma resposta. Isso cabe mais como resposta.

Comment: Mas eu gostaria de saber mesmo se isso influencia ou não no desempenho, se eu responder não seria como se eu já soubesse?

Comment: Então transforme isso em uma pergunta, a mesma que você se fez para buscar esta resposta que postou. Dessa forma, fica tudo dentro do formato do site. ;)

Comment: Obs.: não há problema algum em criar uma pergunta já postando resposta, é até aconselhável, se você tem algum conhecimento e quer compartilhar, isso é bem vindo!

Comment: Mudei a pergunta

Comment: Marcelo, acho que você não entendeu. O campo completo, incluindo o titulo e o corpo, são para **perguntas**. Se você teve uma duvida que encontrou a resposta e quer compartilhar, você deve fazer conforme o **[tour]** explica. Deve separar a pergunta da resposta, pois conforme o tour explica, aqui é um Q&A, este campo que você usou é para a pergunta, o campo abaixo, onde tem o botão "Publique sua resposta" é para resposta. Você deve separar o que é pergunta e deixar nestes 2 campos acima, e o que for solução ou resposta, postar no campo abaixo.

Comment: Ixi, complicou,acho que não entendi mesmo, eu não tenho a resposta, estou colocando o que eu imagino para que me digam se estou errado.

Comment: @Marcelo é isso que ele está dizendo... você perguntou e postou a sua visão que nada mais é uma resposta. Independente de você estar errado ou não você respondeu a sua pergunta no campo de pergunta e não de resposta.

Comment: Seria duplicata de [Comentários pesam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199201/5878) ou apenas relacionada?

Comment: Esquece, deixa como tá, a comunidade decide. Se caso fecharem, você pode questionar o motivo no [meta]

Comment: @Marcelo acho que toda a confusão se deu porque você escreveu uma *redação* para perguntar algo relativamente simples. Ao meu ver, nada que está após o quadro amarelo acrescenta em algo na pergunta e poderia ser removido ser perda de conteúdo. Veja, por exemplo, a pergunta que citei acima. Ela pergunta praticamente a mesma coisa que você - mas com apenas 2 palavras.

Comment: Acho muito amplo para responder, cada interpretador/analisador pode trabalhar de uma forma, não tem resposta para dizer se é ou não custoso a todas linguagens, só testando uma a uma para ter algum parametro, e as vezes a diferença é tão ínfima que nem vale a pena se preocupar com isto para performance, já que muitas linguagens "compilam" para alguma linguagem intermediaria (JIT, claro que nem todas).

Comment: @Articuno, rsrsrs, desculpa ae, realmente não estava entendendo, não sabia que eu deveria colocar minha visão nas respostas.

Comment: @Marcelo sem problemas, eu tinha convicção de algo, mas acabei ficando confuso após debater com outros usuários do site, por isso disse que era pra deixar como tá, nem eu mais sabia se estava certo ou não. xD

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, quanto ao HTML e javascript como citado no link que você passou eu já sabia que por ser interpretado pelo navegador quanto mais linhas mais custo pra maquina do usuário, isso reforça um pouco minha duvida, mas como o delphi é compilado resolvi colocar essa questão aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O uso de mais linhas como nos exemplos acima, será que influencia no desempenho da aplicação?

Em Delphi não influencia em nada neste caso relatado. É claro que um código fonte mal escrito pode acabar gerando um código alvo que desperdice recursos. Mas não por comentário ou por indicador de início e fim de bloco que é puramente sintático.

> Imagino que quanto mais linhas independente de qualquer coisa o processador e memória vão trabalhar um pouco mais, certo?

Não em linguagem compilada, exceto no momento da compilação, mesmo assim será ínfimo. Em linguagem interpretada [tem um custo porque a compilação ocorre no momento da execução e portanto o interpretador tem que trabalhar mais durante a execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190209/101). Mas geralmente o custo é bem pequeno e muda quase nada na execução real do código. Veja [Comentários pesam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199201/101).

> Ou será que o compilador é inteligente o suficiente para ignorar os begins quando se trata de um IF simples?

Não é questão de ser inteligente, é o trabalho dele. O compilador interpreta um texto escrito por um humano e gera um código que a máquina entende. Para a máquina só existe o código realmente útil, não existe coisas sintáticas que só servem para ajudar um humano organizar seu código.

Seria interessante [entender o que um compilador faz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101). Provavelmente também [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Estilo de codificação cada um tem o seu. Código muito longo tende a ser mais difícil de ler. Código espremido demais também. Isso é uma arte. Eu já mudei algumas vezes meu estilo, e acho que cada vez estou no estilo correto, claro. É preciso experiência para entender a "melhor" forma. O último código é meu preferido. Na verdade eu faria tudo em uma linha, pelo menos em outra linguagem.

Comment: "Não é questão de ser inteligente, é o trabalho dele" esse é o ponto, minha intenção é facilitar o trabalha do processador.